# Certificate is ACTIVE but load balancer still shows as insecure connection in browser

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I've followed this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-https-lb-simple#ip-address)

To create a simple https load balancer to my GCE instance.

If I open the GCE instance ephemeral IP in the browser (in HTTP) I get the expected result and everything works as expected

So I wanted to allow https only by adding a load balancer with an SSL certificate. everything seems to be working, the instance group shows to be healthy, and the certificate is ACTIVE and connected to the load balancer's frontend service.
[image]
[image]
But when I load up the lb's in the browser I get a 404 error and I can see that the connection is insecure.
[image]

Any idea what I might be missing to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

You certificate is not pointing to the ip.
It's for https://dev-api.notamimic.com/

[image: Certificate]